# What is the quickest way to build admin interfaces in PHP?

Tags: php, django, user-interface, frameworks

What's the quickest way to build admin interfaces in PHP?

It can be a framework, a library/libraries coupled with a particular approach, or whatever.

Background: I'm a Django developer spoiled by auto admin who has to deliver a web-app in PHP.  The app is very admin-area/form heavy and has different access levels.

Answer (score 5):

On PHP, [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/), which has admin generators, is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I also suggest symfony. 
Zend will be too much for small project.
if you are building blog, then use Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally use http://agiletoolkit.org/  It is done in php but allows you to use one of the best frameworks i have seen to build it.  They have great support and have answered all my questions.

Check out this page on just the surface of what this framework can do.  http://ui.agiletoolkit.org/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/). Haven't tried it but I had this colleague (PM) at work (a Java shop) always ranting about how he could do everything faster and better if we would be using CodeIgniter.

Comment: CodeIgniter is great, but doesn't have built in admin generation.

Comment: He doesn't say that it has to have built-in admin generation Alan, that is just what he is used to with Django.  Why would you -1 someone for suggesting CI?  You are the one who is incorrect here Alan, not cherouvim.

Comment: No worries. My answer had a sense of humor anyway. I just wanted to say it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using a framework for this definitely go with [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/).  Its lightweight [M-V-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) approach really makes project like these a breeze.  I build a lot of database driven administrative applications with PHP and have found CI to be a time saver.

Of course it is entirely possible to accomplish this task using nothing more than vanilla PHP and  libraries.  I have built many administrative / management applications w/o frameworks.

If you have other questions let me/us know.

`-` Nicholas

Comment: If it was you Alan who -1'd me here I would like to point out that your completely out of line for doing so.  The same goes for your response to cherouvim -- the author of this question did NOT say it had to have auto generation.

Comment: cherouvim: LMAO -- nicely put. :)

Comment: The _quickest_ way is *NOT* CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way? Write it by hand. If there's potential for re-use, copy and paste at first, then refactor into libraries. This approach works best if you pretty much know what you're doing. Otherwise, a framework might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried QCodo, which does a lot automatically.